# How to reset PYTHONPATH to earlier value

Tags: python, environment-variables, zsh

I had been tinkering with PYTHONPATH for some work and wrote the following in my `.zshrc` file:

```bsh
export PYTHONPATH="someDirectories:aFewMoreDirectories"
```

I then sourced the `.zshrc` file and then realized that the previous path was no longer available to me. 
I read a post where someone mentioned that `sys.path` in python stores the previous values also, so I tried copying and appending those paths to the present path. When I tried to source the file again, there were errors showing incompatibility of the different python versions in my system. I had checked the `sys.path` from **python3.7** although the default python versions in my system are **python2.7** and **python3.6**.

How can I resolve this issue? Any reply would be of great help.

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to Askubuntu!    Related Link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304802/how-do-i-reset-pythonpath-to-default-value-in-virtualenv   + this one (More informative I want to say):  https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/using_pythonpath.html

Comment: export PYTHONPATH="/usr/bin/python:/usr/bin/python3.7" solved it for me. Anyhow, thanks for the links!

Comment: Ah,   thx gosh.  ^^  Have a great day on you sir!  //Regards